# ClassNotFoundException exception occurred: io.confluent.kafka.security.config.provider.SecurePassConfigProvider (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, apache-kafka-security

The broker is failed on start-up and I can see the following errors :

```
INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
ERROR ClassNotFoundException exception occurred: io.confluent.kafka.security.config.provider.SecurePassConfigProvider (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
ERROR ClassNotFoundException exception occurred: io.confluent.kafka.security.config.provider.SecurePassConfigProvider (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
ERROR ClassNotFoundException exception occurred: io.confluent.kafka.security.config.provider.SecurePassConfigProvider (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
ERROR ClassNotFoundException exception occurred: io.confluent.kafka.security.config.provider.SecurePassConfigProvider (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
INFO KafkaConfig values:
----------------------------
```

I did a secret setup for one of the property(i.e., `ssl.truststore.password`) in `server.properties` file and tried re-starting the server and observed the above error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!!

```
---server.properties---
##
ssl.truststore.password = ${securepass:/home/secret/secrets.txt:server.properties/ssl.truststore.password}

config.providers = securepass
config.providers.securepass.class = io.confluent.kafka.security.config.provider.SecurePassConfigProvider
```

`Confluent Community version used - 5.5.2`

Comment: Are you sure that class exists in version 5.5.2? Did you download any extra security JARs for that class?

Comment: The Confluent v5.5.2 docuemtnations has mentioned about the class `io.confluent.kafka.security.config.provider.SecurePassConfigProvider` 
`(ref# https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.2/security/secrets.html#using-prefixes-in-secrets-configurations)`
So that class should've been available in the package. This's what my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community edition of Confluent Platform 5.5.2 does not come with this class...

```
$ find ./confluent-5.5.2 -name 'kafka-client-plugins*.jar'
```

Download the file here and make sure it is in the Kafka broker classpath, e.g. `/usr/share/java/kafka` if installed directly to the OS, or the `share/java/kafka` folder of the Confluent tarball.

https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-client-plugins/5.5.2-ce/kafka-client-plugins-5.5.2-ce.jar

Verified with

```
$ jar -tf kafka-client-plugins-5.5.2-ce.jar| grep SecurePassConfigProvider
io/confluent/kafka/security/config/provider/SecurePassConfigProvider.class
```

---

Overall, if someone has file-system access to your brokers, you have bigger problems, and obscuring the file with a direct reference to another is not "secure"

Comment: Thank you very much.
But is it the proper way of using those two config parameters? in `server.properties` to encrypt the passwords?

Comment: Also this jar is coming from `confluent enterprise` : https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-client-plugins/`5.5.2-ce`/kafka-client-plugins-5.5.2-ce.jar

Is it safe to include it in community version? as I'm not using enterprise version?

Comment: `ce` means Community Edition, IIRC. `ccs` is for Confluent/Cloud Server (or enterprise)

Comment: Hmm, no, got that backwards. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/available_packages.html#platform-packages I mean, you can try it. Typically, the only limitation with the enterprise packages is that they require a licensing topic to be defined, but I don't see that in this plugins documentation